# Своя идеальная админка на Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Решил не пользоваться готовыми, а сделать под себя идеальную админку на ларавел-проекте.

И в самом начале назрел вопрос. Можно как-нибудь в маршрутах/роутах указать что путь `/admin` лишь для "избранных", и чтобы он туда и во все его подмаршруты обычных юзеров не пускал?

А то у меня пока одна мысль: в каждом методе каждого класса админки постоянно прописывать условие на проверку статуса юзера. Но это же плохой код.

Если в роутах это не прописывается, то подскажите хотя бы оптимальное решение.

Comment: В хранить отдельно обычные пути и "для избранных" ; подгружать только нужные.

Comment: middleware в роут прописать

Comment: https://github.com/SmartCrowd/laravel-rbac

Answer (score 9, accepted):

для начала создайте middleware admin

```
php artisan make:middleware admin
```

затем добавьте в model user этот код

```
// is admin
public function isAdmin()
{
return $this->is_admin; // поле is_admin в таблице users
}
```

дальше откройте middleware admin и добавьте этот код

```
// проверяем принадлежность пользователя
if ( Auth::check() && Auth::user()->isAdmin()==true )
{
    return $next($request);
}
return redirect('/');
```

в App\Http\Kernel.php в protected $routeMiddleware добавить наш middleware

```
'admin'=>\App\Http\Middleware\admin::class,
```

и наконец в роуте

```
Route::group( [ 'middleware' => 'admin', 'prefix' => 'admin' ], function () {
// только для админа
});
```

Comment: можно ещё вот так написать

Route::get('/admin', function () {
    return view('admin.dashboard');
})->middleware('admin.dashboard');

Answer (score 3):

Здравствуйте, знаю эту тему создали год назад, но я столкнулся с тем же и два предыдущих Коментарии не сработали пришлось делать самому.

Laravel **5.5**:

Создаем Регистрацию\Авторизацию: `php artisan migrate:auth`

Создайте механизм для фильтрации:

В терминале: `php artisan make:middleware Access`

**Откройте App\Http\Middleware\Access.php**

**Добавьте :**

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $role)
{

  switch($role){
    case 'admin':
    if(!\Auth::user()){
      if($request->ajax())
        return response('Access Denied')->setStatusCode(403);
      abort(404);
    }else
    if(!$request->user()->is_admin){
      if($request->ajax())
        return response('Access Denied')->setStatusCode(403);
      abort(404);
    }
    break;
    default:
    return response('Access Denied')->setStatusCode(403);
    break;
  }

  return $next($request);
}
```

**Откройте App\Http\Kernel.php**

В переменную `$routeMiddleware` с массивом запишите:

```
'access' => \App\Http\Middleware\Access::class,
```

**Откройте App/User.php**

В переменную **$hidden** с массивом запишите: `'is_admin'`

**Откройте Routes/Web.php**

В самый конец вставьте:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth', 'middleware' => 'access:admin'], function () {
  // Здесь продолжайте свое творение
  Route::get('dashboard', function() { echo "HELLO WORLD"; } );
});
```

**Откройте database/migrations/2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table.php**

И запишите в таблицу новую колонку, а именно:

```
    $table->bigInteger('is_admin')->default(0);
```

Сохраняем и теперь в терминале `php artisan migrate:reset` удаляем все мигрированные таблицы, а теперь мигрируем новые `php artisan migrate`

**Зарегистрируйте пользователя.**

Теперь заходим в свою базу и смотрим что в таблице 'Users' появилась колонка **is_admin** с значение **0** это значит что вы не админ, что бы вы стали админом ставим значение **1**

Проверяем зайдите по ссылке mysite.com/dashboard если вы видите HELLO WORLD значит вы админ если нет тогда вы не админ.

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'admin', 'middleware' => 'auth'], function() {

}
```

Comment: Не забывайте использовать разметку в ответах и не оставляйте куски кода без пояснений даже если он очень понятный